# Can not call Auth class inside Scope class in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I added External Scope for User Model. Simply created Scope, with the name `DeveloperScope`

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Auth;

class DeveloperScope implements Scope
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->id != 1){
            $builder->where('id', '<>', 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I called this scope for User model.

**User Model**

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use App\Models\Scopes\DeveloperScope;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;


    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password'];

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new DeveloperScope);
    }
}
```

It works well, when I don't use `Auth::class` inside `DeveloperScope` class. The reason is that, I just want to hide the main user for another users for all Eloquent methods. Of course, I can use session instead of Auth and retrieve user id. But it is still interesting for me, why browser gives an error: `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` while using `Auth::class` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method what you are looking for is exactly **`Auth::hasUser()`**. The method was added in Laravel 5.6 through my PR. (So you need to upgrade Laravel first)

[[5.6] Add ability to determine if the current user is ALREADY authenticated without triggering side effects by mpyw · Pull Request #24518 · laravel/framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/24518)

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class DeveloperScope implements Scope
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        if (!Auth::hasUser() || Auth::user()->id != 1) {
            $builder->where('id', '<>', 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Just call `Auth::hasUser()` to prevent `Auth::user()` from causing side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Try injecting the `Illuminate\Auth\Guard` class and then call the user method on it. e.g.:

`$this->auth->user();`

You should be fine with just type-hinting it since Laravel will automatically new up an instance for you.

For more info check out the API: https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.html

Comment: As I understand, you mean calling __construct function and retrieve auth.  Why inject Guard? We could just inject Auth. But both of them will not work. I tried. Also, it is possible just return `Auth::user()` from construct. Now, this will work :) But this will duplicate sql.

Comment: The Auth facade points to Illuminate\Auth\Guard so that should work. And Auth::user() will not have duplicate SQL because if the user isn't in the session it will fetch it, otherwise it will just receive it from the session store.

Comment: `public function __construct(Guard $auth){$this->auth = $auth->user();}` right?

Comment: No, just $this->auth = $auth and then use it like this: $this->auth->user();

Comment: The problem is not coming from  `construct`. in my  `User` model I can't  instantiate interface Guard. However, `static::addGlobalScope(new DeveloperScope)` is missing `$auth`. Can't figure out how to call `$auth` in my scope. `static::addGlobalScope(new DeveloperScope (new Guard) )` is not working too.

Comment: You're using the Auth instance in the scope class not the User class, so instantiate it there.